# How to use Galerkin approximation to find the existence of weak solution.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let's consider $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^3$ , $T\ge 0 , \Omega_T=\Omega \times(0,T]$

Consider the problem

$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
&u_t-\Delta u+u^3=f,\qquad&&\text{on}\;\Omega_T,\\ 
&u=0,\qquad&&\text{for}\;x\in\partial \Omega,\;t\ge0,\\ 
&u=g,\qquad&&\text{for}\;x\in \Omega,\;t=0,  
\end{align}
\right.
$$

where $f$ and $g$ belong to $L^2(\Omega_T)$ and $L^2 (\Omega)$ respectively.

How can I show that there exists weak solution using Galerkin's approximation?

Any kind of help will be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Galerkin will work, but semigroup approach is easier.

Answer (score 2):

What have you use so far? Why Galerkin method?

As for the stationary problem, $-\Delta u + u^3 = f$, it can be reduced to an abstract Hammerstein equation. This is described in a way more general setting in [Michael Holst, Ari Stern: Semilinear mixed problems on Hilbert complexes and their numerical approximation](http://arxiv.org/abs/1010.6127), but they say you need a maximum principle for the equation in order to apply their theory.